# How to offer users sign in during purchase?

Tags: user-expectation, registration

I am working on cinema website. We allow users buy tickets without registration, but the main business requirement is motivate users sign in/sign up during purchase process - after click on seat you see notification, that offer you to sign in, sign up or continue as guest.

So I am confused at which step to offer users sign in and how to do that with minimal risk of breaking the deal. Should it be pop-up or just text notification? Should it be when user choose screening time, choose seats, or make checkout?

Comment: Practically every other e-commerce site does this. One of the early steps when designing a thing is to see how it's done elsewhere. This allows us to use patterns that users are already familiar with. Is there something about the way others do this that won't work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When offering users to sign up on your site, you actually have to give them convincing advantages that are worth it. Especially in this time of the internet where people are scared of every company stealing their data.

Here are some general ideas to implement it on any site that contains a checkout process:

---

### Before Checkout

As a motivator for this you can simply have a **box with account benefits** somewhere on your site.

(Be careful with showing them in a pop-up, as that can [potentially damage your brand](https://unbounce.com/email-marketing/get-subscribers-from-pop-ups/). They do seem to work under good conditions, though ([1](https://www.activecampaign.com/blog/do-pop-ups-work/), [2](https://sumo.com/stories/pop-up-statistics)).)

[image]

---

### During Checkout

Here you can offer them the choice upon entering checkout.

**1. Log in**
 **2. Sign up**
 **3. Continue as guest**

Or you can make it easier or more "seamless" by simply adding a **checkbox at the end of the data form** in the checkout process (similar to the image below).

It can then say "Create an account with this data". Make it easy to spot and read though, so it does not seem like some scam.

[image]

---

### After Checkout

This one is, in my opinion, the best option for the customer.

After the checkout you can show the usual confimation with "thanks....etc." and right beneath that you show an **already filled out form where only the password is missing**. Here you offer the customer to sign up and show him some benefits (similar to the screenshot below, but this one only shows the password fields).

At this stage, they already entered their data anyway and already paid the money, so they do not feel as threatened by it as before the checkout.

[image]